# 20 identical red balls, 20 identical blue balls, 20 identical green balls, 1 white ball, and 1 black ball. You draw 15. How many outcomes?

Tags: combinatorics, multisets

A bag contains 20 identical red balls, 20 identical blue balls, 20 identical green balls, 1 white ball, and 1 black ball. I reach in to get 15 balls. How many outcomes are there? The problem came from a section that teaches multisets so I am required to use $k+n-1\choose k$.

My attempt:
$$\text{Case 1: No white and black balls}$$
$$\text{No. of ways = $17\choose 2$}$$
$$\text{Case 2: With white ball only}$$
$$\text{No. of ways = $16\choose 2$}$$
$$\text{Case 3: With black ball only}$$
$$\text{No. of ways = $16\choose 2$}$$
$$\text{Case 4: With white and black}$$
$$\text{No. of ways = $15\choose 2$}$$
Hence, the total number of outcomes is ${17\choose 2}+{16\choose 2}+{16\choose 2}+{15\choose 2}$

Comment: $$\text{Why type like this?}$$

Comment: Are you considering the order of colors in the outcomes or only the number of balls from each color?

Comment: I think the order does not matter. This problem came from a section that teaches how to count multisets.

Comment: I agree with your analysis, which seems to be based on [Stars and Bars theory](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/), which is also discussed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).  That is, the number of non-negative integer solutions to $$x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_k = n ~: ~n,k \in \Bbb{Z^+}$$ is $~\displaystyle \binom{n+k-1}{k-1},~$ which you applied correctly, but mis-stated in the first paragraph of your posting.

Comment: I am not sure if the intuition I used behind these cases is correct, that is, to assume I drew 1 white ball or 1 black ball already and just find the number of ways to create multisets from the remaining balls.

Comment: That is exactly how I approached the problem.

Comment: Oh, I see, thank you